# sed and it's regex for optional symbols

Tags: regex, sed

I'm writing a script for splitting big FLAC audio files to small pieces according to cue list. I use cueprint for determining tag information, but in some cases it does not provide what I need and I need to use sed for digging info directly from cue file. Now I'm fighting GENRE thing. The trouble with it is that it comes in different ways:

```
REM GENRE "Gothic"
REM GENRE Gothic
```

are both seem to be withing standart, but very difficult to parse.
For the second case something like

```
sed -nr -e "s/^(REM GENRE )(.*)\r/\2/p" *.cue
```

work perfectly and return Gothic as expected. But for the first case "Gothic" is returned, which isn't what I wont wore feather processing.
Well, you'll say "use an "optional" quotes in the first and third part of the regex, like this

```
sed -nr -e "s/^(REM GENRE \"?)(.*)\"?\r/\2/p" *.cue
```

But this does not work as expected, the result is

```
Gothic"
```

with a trailing double quote.

Any ides how to parse both quoted and unquoted string with sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` matches greedily. When you match `(.*)"?`, `.*` matches `Gothic"`, and `"?` matches an empty string. You'll have to exclude double quotes from the `.*` string, e.g.

```
sed -nr 's/^REM GENRE "?([^"]*)"?\r?/\1/p' *.cue
```

Note that this will cause trouble with quoted strings that cotain quotes, as in `"Goth\"ic"`. To avoid this problem, a little larger guns are required. I'd suggest

```
sed -nr '/^REM GENRE "?(([^"]|\\")*)"?\r?/ { s//\1/; s/\\"/"/g; p; }'
```

That is

```
/^REM GENRE "?(([^"]|\\")*)"?\r?/ {   # if a line contains the pattern
  s//\1/                              # isolate the capturing group
  s/\\"/"/g                           # unescape quotes
  p                                   # then print.
}
```

Note the `([^"]|\\")*` in the regex that matches non-quote characters and escaped quotes.

Comment: Very nice. Doesn't work for quoted word though: `REM GENRE "Gothic" "word"`

Comment: That's true. Does the cueprint format allow that sort of thing?

Comment: Well, I don't think that something like "Gothic" "rock" is "expectable" in that case, I don't even think something like Goth\"ic is what I will ever see there. So, both suggested answers will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `(.*)` in the middle to `([^\"]*)` to exclude quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this,

```
sed -nr -e 's/^(REM GENRE )"?([^"\r]*)/\2/p' *.cue
```